# GCP Python Compute Engine - list VM's

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have the following Python3 script:

```
import os, json
import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('gcp-sa.json')
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)

compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')

def list_instances(compute, project, zone):
    result = compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone).execute()
    return result['items'] if 'items' in result else None

list_instances(compute, "my-project", "my-zone")
```

Only listing buckets without the rest works fine, that tells me that my service account (with has read access to the whole project) should work. How can I now list VM's? Using the code above, I get

```
raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

So that tells me that I somehow have to pass the service account json. How is that possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: You are specifying the service account in the first part and not specifying the service account in the second part. Look into `credenteials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('gcp-sa.json')` and `googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1' credentials=credentials)`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!